# xsl column size and alignment

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xsl file and xml file - As you can see in the screenshot _ am not being able to put the column titles for county and city on the same first row of the table as ID, State, Capital. Given county is child of state and city is child of county I put it in template. But I am not being able to align the column headers with the fields. Also I am not being able to fix the column size for the child elements as for the parent columns.I tried to use width and colspan but nothing changes. Thanks for your help.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>


    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
          <head>
            <title>Books</title>
          </head>
          <body>
            <table width="100%" border="1">
              <THEAD>
            <TR>
              <TD width="5%" style="white-space: nowrap; text-overflow:ellipsis; overflow: hidden; max-width:1px;">
                <B>ID</B>
              </TD>
              <TD width="10%">
                <B>State</B>
              </TD>
              <TD width="15%">
                <B>Capital</B>
              </TD>
              <TD width="10%">
                <B>CountyName</B>
              </TD>
              <TD width="10%">
                <B>CountyName</B>
              </TD>
               <TD width="10%">
                <B>CityName</B>
              </TD>
               <TD width="10%">
                <B>CityArea</B>
              </TD>
             
            </TR>
          </THEAD>
          <TBODY>
            <xsl:for-each select="geo_DB/geo_db/state">
              <TR>
                <TD width="200px"  style="white-space: nowrap; text-overflow:ellipsis; overflow: hidden; max-width:1px;">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
                </TD>
                <TD width="30px">
                  <xsl:value-of select="stateName" />
                </TD>              
                <TD width="15%">
                  <xsl:value-of select="stateCapital" />
                </TD>
               
                <TD width="70%">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="county" />
                </TD>
               
              </TR>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </TBODY>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="county">
    <table border="1">
      <!--thead>
        <TR>
          <TD width="15%">
            <B>Name</B>
          </TD>
          <TD width="10%">
            <B>Area</B>
          </TD>
          <TD width="65%">
            <B>Cities</B>
          </TD>

        </TR>
      </thead-->
      <TBODY>
    <TR>
      <TD width="25%">
        <xsl:value-of select="countyName" />
      </TD>     
      <TD width="10%">
        <xsl:value-of select="countyArea" />
      </TD>
      <TD colspan="4" width="65%">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="city" />
      </TD>

    </TR>
      </TBODY>
    </table>
     </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="city">
    <table border="1">
      <TBODY>
        <TR>
          <TD width="35%">
            <xsl:value-of select="cityName" />
          </TD>
          <TD width="40%">
            <xsl:value-of select="cityPopulation" />
          </TD>
        </TR>
      </TBODY>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>



 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="multiTER.xsl"?>
<geo_DB xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="XMLFIle.xsd">
  <!-- Geo database-->
  <geo_db>
<!-- This is a state-->
<state id = "state1">
  <stateName>Missouri</stateName>
  <stateCapital>Jefferson</stateCapital>
  <!-- This is a country-->
  <county>
    <countyName>Jackson</countyName>
    <countyArea>4.2</countyArea>
    <countyLocation>
      <countyLatitude>52.3</countyLatitude>
      <countyLongitude>53.3</countyLongitude>
    </countyLocation>

    <!-- This is a city-->
    <city>
      <cityName>Kansas</cityName>
      <cityPopulation>45</cityPopulation>
      <cityLocation>
        <cityLatitude>52.31</cityLatitude>
        <cityLongitude>53.31</cityLongitude>
      </cityLocation>
    </city>
    <!-- This is another city-->
    <city>
      <cityName>City in Jackson</cityName>
      <cityPopulation>55</cityPopulation>
      <cityLocation>
        <cityLatitude>52.32</cityLatitude>
        <cityLongitude>53.32</cityLongitude>
      </cityLocation>
    </city>

  </county>
  <!-- This is another country-->
  <county>
    <countyName>Greene</countyName>
    <countyArea>2</countyArea>
    <countyLocation>
      <countyLatitude>52.8</countyLatitude>
      <countyLongitude>53.8</countyLongitude>
    </countyLocation>
    <city>
      <cityName>temp</cityName>
      <cityPopulation>4578</cityPopulation>
      <cityLocation>
        <cityLatitude>10.8</cityLatitude>
        <cityLongitude>25.9</cityLongitude>
      </cityLocation>
    </city>
  </county>

</state>

<!-- This is another state-->
<state id="state2">
  <stateName>Ontario</stateName>
  <stateCapital>Toronto</stateCapital>
  <county>
    <countyName>Frontenac</countyName>
    <countyArea>3787</countyArea>
    <countyLocation>
      <countyLatitude>23.8</countyLatitude>
      <countyLongitude>12.9</countyLongitude>
    </countyLocation>
    <city>
      <cityName>Kingston</cityName>
      <cityPopulation>123787</cityPopulation>
      <cityLocation>
        <cityLatitude>45.4</cityLatitude>
        <cityLongitude>23.1</cityLongitude>
      </cityLocation>
    </city>
  </county>
</state>


<state id="state3">
      <stateName>Alabama</stateName>
      <stateCapital>Montgomery</stateCapital>
      <county>
        <countyName>Autaaga</countyName>
        <countyArea>1212</countyArea>
        <countyLocation>
          <countyLatitude>23.8</countyLatitude>
          <countyLongitude>12.9</countyLongitude>
        </countyLocation>
        <city>
          <cityName>Millbrock</cityName>
          <cityPopulation>412</cityPopulation>
          <cityLocation>
            <cityLatitude>49.4</cityLatitude>
            <cityLongitude>29.1</cityLongitude>
          </cityLocation>
        </city>
      </county>
      <county>
        <countyName>Baldwin </countyName>
        <countyArea>43344</countyArea>
        <countyLocation>
          <countyLatitude>49.8</countyLatitude>
          <countyLongitude>29.9</countyLongitude>
        </countyLocation>
        <city>
          <cityName>Bay Minette</cityName>
          <cityPopulation>7856</cityPopulation>
          <cityLocation>
            <cityLatitude>49.4</cityLatitude>
            <cityLongitude>29.1</cityLongitude>
          </cityLocation>
        </city>
      </county>
      <county>
        <countyName>Barbour </countyName>
        <countyArea>777</countyArea>
        <countyLocation>
          <countyLatitude>23.8</countyLatitude>
          <countyLongitude>12.9</countyLongitude>
        </countyLocation>
        <city>
          <cityName>Cilo</cityName>
          <cityPopulation>7856</cityPopulation>
          <cityLocation>
            <cityLatitude>49.4</cityLatitude>
            <cityLongitude>29.1</cityLongitude>
          </cityLocation>
        </city>
        <city>
          <cityName>Eufaula</cityName>
          <cityPopulation>44</cityPopulation>
          <cityLocation>
            <cityLatitude>49.4</cityLatitude>
            <cityLongitude>29.1</cityLongitude>
          </cityLocation>
        </city>
      </county>
    </state>
    <state id="state4">
      <stateName>Arizona</stateName>
      <stateCapital>Phoenix</stateCapital>
      <county>
        <countyName>Apache</countyName>
        <countyArea>1212</countyArea>
        <countyLocation>
          <countyLatitude>23.8</countyLatitude>
          <countyLongitude>12.9</countyLongitude>
        </countyLocation>
        <city>
          <cityName>St-John</cityName>
          <cityPopulation>412</cityPopulation>
          <cityLocation>
            <cityLatitude>49.4</cityLatitude>
            <cityLongitude>29.1</cityLongitude>
          </cityLocation>
        </city>
      </county>
      <county>
        <countyName>Cochise </countyName>
        <countyArea>43344</countyArea>
        <countyLocation>
          <countyLatitude>49.8</countyLatitude>
          <countyLongitude>29.9</countyLongitude>
        </countyLocation>
        <city>
          <cityName>Benson</cityName>
          <cityPopulation>7856</cityPopulation>
          <cityLocation>
            <cityLatitude>49.4</cityLatitude>
            <cityLongitude>29.1</cityLongitude>
          </cityLocation>
        </city>
      </county>
      <county>
        <countyName>Coconino </countyName>
        <countyArea>777</countyArea>
        <countyLocation>
          <countyLatitude>23.8</countyLatitude>
          <countyLongitude>12.9</countyLongitude>
        </countyLocation>
        <city>
          <cityName>Flagstaff</cityName>
          <cityPopulation>7856</cityPopulation>
          <cityLocation>
            <cityLatitude>49.4</cityLatitude>
            <cityLongitude>29.1</cityLongitude>
          </cityLocation>
        </city>
        <city>
          <cityName>Page</cityName>
          <cityPopulation>44</cityPopulation>
          <cityLocation>
            <cityLatitude>49.4</cityLatitude>
            <cityLongitude>29.1</cityLongitude>
          </cityLocation>
        </city>
      </county>
    </state>

<state id = "state5">
      <stateName>Colorado</stateName>
      <stateCapital>Denver</stateCapital>
      <!-- This is a country-->
      <county>
        <countyName>Adams</countyName>
        <countyArea>4.2</countyArea>
        <countyLocation>
          <countyLatitude>52.3</countyLatitude>
          <countyLongitude>53.3</countyLongitude>
        </countyLocation>

        <!-- This is a city-->
        <city>
          <cityName>Arvada</cityName>
          <cityPopulation>45</cityPopulation>
          <cityLocation>
            <cityLatitude>52.31</cityLatitude>
            <cityLongitude>53.31</cityLongitude>
          </cityLocation>
        </city>
        <!-- This is another city-->
        <city>
          <cityName>Aurora</cityName>
          <cityPopulation>578525</cityPopulation>
          <cityLocation>
            <cityLatitude>52.32</cityLatitude>
            <cityLongitude>53.32</cityLongitude>
          </cityLocation>
        </city>

      </county>
      <!-- This is another country-->
      <county>
        <countyName>Crowley</countyName>
        <countyArea>2</countyArea>
        <countyLocation>
          <countyLatitude>52.8</countyLatitude>
          <countyLongitude>53.8</countyLongitude>
        </countyLocation>
        <city>
          <cityName>Olney</cityName>
          <cityPopulation>64445</cityPopulation>
          <cityLocation>
            <cityLatitude>10.8</cityLatitude>
            <cityLongitude>25.9</cityLongitude>
          </cityLocation>
        </city>
      </county>

    </state>
<state id = "state6">
      <stateName>Connecticut</stateName>
      <stateCapital>Hartford</stateCapital>
     
      <!-- This is  country-->
      <county>
        <countyName>Fairfield</countyName>
        <countyArea>2</countyArea>
        <countyLocation>
          <countyLatitude>52.8</countyLatitude>
          <countyLongitude>53.8</countyLongitude>
        </countyLocation>
        <city>
          <cityName>Stamford</cityName>
          <cityPopulation>45466</cityPopulation>
          <cityLocation>
            <cityLatitude>10.8</cityLatitude>
            <cityLongitude>25.9</cityLongitude>
          </cityLocation>
        </city>
      </county>

    </state>

  </geo_db>
</geo_DB>
```

[image: Screenshot of table]

Comment: Do you simply want to produce one table row for each city? Do you need to nested tables?

Comment: What i need is the first row contains all the header names - so i do not want to have the column titles in the nested tables but in the first row of the main table itself. Yes one table row for each city of course its association with the county and state should be clear.